# Sender of event in NodeJS EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

In a NodeJS app that fork several child processes I need to know when child process exits, the problem is the callback function invoked by the EventEmitter does not have the sender of the event.

I've done lots of .NET development and their event always has `sender` parameter and `arguments` parameter.

How can I know which child process sent the event?

I can do something like

`const childProcess = fork(...)
childProcess.on('exit', function(code, signal) { 
  myCallback(childProcess, code, signal); 
}`

but then I wont be able to unregister from that specific event handler.

Comment: Pardon me, you're saying that you need to now who exactly sent the kill signal to your `childProcess`? Why?

Comment: In Javascript, you have access to the parent scope when the event handler was called and you can arrange for the parent scope to have a variable in it that identifies which child process it is.  If you show us the larger context for how you're creating multiple child processes, then we could advise you more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `this` will be set to reference the sender.

Source [https://nodejs.org/api/events.html](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners)

> The eventEmitter.emit() method allows an arbitrary set of arguments to
>   be passed to the listener functions. It is important to keep in mind
>   that when an ordinary listener function is called by the EventEmitter,
>   the standard this keyword is intentionally set to reference the
>   EventEmitter to which the listener is attached.

Answer (score 0):

cluster.worker.pid is usually a great way to get the ID of the process (as fork causes such an event).

console.log(cluster.worker.pid);

Comment: Thanks but in the parent process I listen to several child processes 'exit' event, I need to know which child send the event. process.pid will always give me the parent process pid